# how to configure camel route for using transactions with database

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint, apache-servicemix

I need to handle transactions with OSGI applications under Karaf(I am using ServiceMix 7.0). All logic is under camel route.
First, I receive Web Requests and process it in route, make transformations and then I need to start transaction : call storedProcedures in Oracle, call another web service and if call to web service is successfull I need to commit stored procedure invocation, otherwise rollback. May be using container managed transactions as in EJB or JTA. 
Camel doesn't have out of box components  for calling stored procedure. So I am using org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure. And now I don't know how to make SP invokation with transactional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
from("direct:mainRoute")
   .transacted()
   .to("direct:invokeService")
   .to("sql-stored:SUBNUMBERS(INTEGER ${headers.num1},INTEGER ${headers.num2},OUT INTEGER resultofsub)
```

You will also need to add TransactionManager to the context.

```
<!-- spring transaction manager -->
<!-- this is the transaction manager Camel will use for transacted routes -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

For more details on Camel SQL stored proc Component refer to:
http://camel.apache.org/sql-stored-procedure.html

Comment: it is very interesting. I don't even know about component sql-stored. It is cool. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my camel to version 2.17.5 But when I am trying to invoke SP it gives me error:Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.ParseException: Encountered " " " "  "" at line 1, column 35.
Was expecting one of:
    <NUMBER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...

Comment: This my invokation                     <setHeader headerName="test">
                        <simple>John</simple>
                    </setHeader>
                    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="value: ${headers.test}" />
                    <to uri="sql-stored:HELLO(VARCHAR ${headers.test},OUT  VARCHAR outparam1)?dataSource=oracleDataSource"/>

Comment: Maciavelli, I haven't faced the issue you are mentioning. And there is no way for me to investigate this. Please share some more details on code - and I can try to reproduce this error. Just to be sure that you have upgraded all Camel jars and there is no mismatch between Camel jar files..

Comment: One this for sure.. For calling a stored proc - It is very tough to write own custom component and still have transaction capabilities.  Transaction mgmt is Camel's forte - and we shouldn't - as application programmers - get into. You can, however, write a compensating Stored Proc - and execute that in case of failures - in case that address your usecase..

Comment: Hi, It was syntax mistake, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619574/stored-procedure-invokation-through-camel-sql-stored-component. Thanks, it works!